# SQL Tree find anscestors at a specific level

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, t-sql

Say I have the following tree:

```
CREATE TABLE Tree(Id int, ParentId int, Name varchar(20), Level int)

INSERT INTO Tree(Id, ParentId, Name, Level)
SELECT 1, NULL, 'Bob', 0 UNION ALL 
SELECT 2, 1, 'John', 1 UNION ALL
SELECT 3, 1, 'Bill', 1 UNION ALL
SELECT 4, 3, 'Peter', 2 UNION ALL
SELECT 5, 4, 'Sarah', 3
```

I need a script to find the ancestor of a given node at a specific level:

For example the ancestor of Sarah at level 2 is Peter, and the ancestor of Peter at level 0 is Bob.

Is there an easy way to do this using a hierarchical CTE? [sqlfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/b0572)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can do this:

```
;WITH TreeCTE
AS
(
    SELECT Id, ParentId, Name, Level
    FROM Tree
    WHERE Id = 5
    UNION ALL 
    SELECT t.Id, t.ParentId, t.Name, t.Level
    FROM TreeCTE AS c
    INNER JOIN Tree t ON c.ParentId = t.Id  
)
SELECT * FROM TreeCTE;
```

This will give you the parent-child chain beginning from `Sarah` with the `id = 5` ending with the top most parent with the `parentid = NULL`.

Here is [**the updated sql fiddle**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/b0572/1)

Answer (score 3):

```
declare @fromid int, @level int
select @fromid = 5, @level = 2 -- for sarah's ancestor at level 2
select @fromid = 4, @level = 0 -- for peter's ancestor at level 0

;with cte as (    
    select * from tree where id = @fromId
    union all
    select t.Id, t.ParentId, t.Name, t.Level from cte
        inner join tree t on t.id = cte.ParentId
) 
    select * from cte
    where Level=@level
```

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
DEclare @level int=0
Declare @name varchar(10)='Peter'
;WITH CTE as (
select * from tree where Name=@name
UNION ALL
select t.* from Tree t inner join CTE c on
t.ID=c.ParentId and t.Level >=@level)
select top 1 Name as Ancestor from CTE order by id
```